# How to change my output from 10.000 to 10

Tags: c

I've just started learning c++ and I saw a question where I need to find out the largest number among n entered numbers. I want to change the output from 10.0000 to 10, but I don't know how to do it? `

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{  
    int n,i;
    float c,big;   
    scanf("%d", &n);
    printf("", n);
    scanf("%f", &big);
    for(i = 2; i <= n; i++)
    {
        printf("", i);
        scanf("%f", &c);
        if(big < c)  
            big = c;    
    }

    printf("%f",n, big);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You mean C, rather than C++?

Comment: You are using %f. This means it will print it in floating point format. You can cast it to int. or use %d.

Comment: Well I tried it in both(c,c++) and that worked but not with my desired output

Comment: Consider `printf("%.0f\n", big);`

Comment: Also, you can't `printf` a zero-length string..

Comment: Well I don't think the problem will be solved with turning %f to %d otherwise it'll brake my code and the output would be your first input here!

Comment: Your `printf()` calls need to have as many `%something` as variables to print.

Comment: Do you want to get rid of all fractions, or only if the fraction is `0`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace this line

```
      printf("%f",n, big);
```

with

```
     printf("%.0f", big);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help bro! but what if I want write it with c++ not c. could you help me with that one ?

Answer (score 1):

Comments on top of each method explain it all. You need to pick the right method based on your requirement.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>

int main()
{  
    float a = 15.567125;
    float b = 15.432345;
    
    /* Method 01
       When you want to consider 3 or 0 digits after integer part */    
    printf("M11: a = %0.3f & b = %0.3f\n",a, b);
    printf("M12: a = %0.0f & b = %0.0f\n",a, b);
    
    /* Method 02
       When you want to ceil or floor the output */    
    printf("M21: a = %0.0f & b = %0.0f\n",ceil(a), ceil(b));
    printf("M21: a = %0.0f & b = %0.0f\n",floor(a), floor(b));
    
    /* Method 03 
       When you simply want to eliminate data after integer part */
    int a1 = a;
    int b1 = b;
    printf("M31: a = %d & b = %d\n",a1, b1);
    printf("M32: a = %d & b = %d\n",(int)a, (int)b);
  
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the output:

```
M11: a = 15.567 & b = 15.432
M12: a = 16 & b = 15
M21: a = 16 & b = 16
M21: a = 15 & b = 15
M31: a = 15 & b = 15
M32: a = 15 & b = 15
```